# Generic parent Collection split to child collections

Tags: c#, list, .net-3.5, ienumerable

I have a list of `IAnimal`

```
List<IAnimal> Animals
```

Inside this list I have 3 different `Animal`

1. `Cat` 5 objects
2. `Dog` 10 objects
3. `Cow` 3 objects

How can I generate 3 different lists of the sub `Animal` type?

Result should be

1. `List<Cat> Cats` contains 5 objects
2. `List<Dog> Dogs` contains 10 objects
3. `List<Cow> Cows` contains 3 objects

I don't mind of using different collection type then `List`. `IEnumerable` or any others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ makes this simple:

```
var cats = animals.OfType<Cat>().ToList();
var dogs = animals.OfType<Dog>().ToList();
var cows = animals.OfType<Cow>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

How about just using [`Enumerable.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) ?

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>
An IEnumerable<T> that contains elements from the input sequence of type TResult.
```

---

```
var cat = animals.OfType<Cat>().ToList();
var cow = animals.OfType<Cow>().ToList();
var dog = animals.OfType<Dog>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your list using `foreach` or `LINQ` and check for the type:

```
 foreach(IAnimal animal in Animals){
  if(animal is Cat)
     Cats.Append(animal);
 //do the same with dogs and cows
 }
```

Comment: Note that you'd have to cast, and the method is `Add`, not `Append`.